# Which is the better way to return a new instance of a boost intrusive_ptr

Tags: c++

Unlike most(?) smart pointers, boost::intrusive_ptr has a non-explicit constructor. Given that, one could write

```
typedef boost::intrusive_ptr<Foo> FooPtr;

FooPtr MyFactory()
{
    return new Foo(a, b, c);
}
```

Or one could write

```
FooPtr MyFactory()
{
    return FooPtr(new Foo(a, b, c));
}
```

The latter is more consistent with how the code would have to be written if FooPtr were another kind of smart pointer, like shared_ptr or unique_ptr. The former is more concise. I personally prefer concise as long as it doesn't lead to trouble for readers and maintainers later. I'm wondering whether the former case is "too" concise?

Comment: On a side note, I subscribe to [Linus Torvalds' opinion on typedefs](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0206.1/0402.html) in as much as they are overused and not always a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, be explicit.  While both of the functions given will work, the second expresses programmer intent more clearly.  Adding a comment along the lines of "This will call intrusive_ptr's implicit constructor" to the first can help, though at that point it's more concise to call the constructor directly.  Returning a raw pointer and relying on the implicit constructor for `intrusive_ptr` may also be viewed as a mistake introduced by changing the declaration of `MyFactory()` but forgetting its definition.  Relying on implicit constructors may also make the code harder to debug and maintain because by default, the constructor for `intrusive_ptr` increments the retain count in `Foo`.  Calling it explicitly gives you the benefit of being able to search for "FooPtr(" when trying to track down every place a `Foo` is  retained.  Also, if the `Foo` constructor initializes its retain count to 1, you may be introducing a memory leak by relying on the implicit constructor.  Explicitly specifying `FooPtr(new Foo(a, b, c), false)` would prevent this.